# how to login on facebook using facebook graph api

Tags: vb.net, facebook-graph-api

I need to login on facebook directly using facebook api without facebook login dialogue box.

Is there any API available for the same?

Answer (score 0):

As the Facebook Login is based on OAuth, there is no way to not show the permission dialog, because the user needs to interact when giving the permissions to a third-party app.

Please refer to the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.3